# Calling FloatLayout class from python file does not work in my kivy file

Tags: python, kivy

I've been working on a python + kv script that can change between screens (login screen, home screen, preferences screen), but I've encountered an error I can't seem to resolve on my own:

**Python script**

```
    # importing library
import kivy

# version
kivy.require('1.11.1')

# importing functionality
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen

# defining screens
class LoginWindow(Screen):
    pass
class PreferencesWindow(Screen):
    pass
class HomeWindow(Screen):
    pass
class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

# define kv file to call
kv = Builder.load_file('my.kv')

# background
Window.clearcolor = (0.67, 0.83, 0.88, 1)

# creating layout class
class MyFloatLayout(FloatLayout):
    username = ObjectProperty(None)
    password = ObjectProperty(None)

    # defining processing method of the login button
    def on_press(self):
        # print is just to check if method is called properly
        print("Username: ", self.username.text, "Password: ", self.password.text)

        """
        Hier komt de verwerking van het inloggen, als het goed is gemaakt door Tim H
        """

        app.root.current = "home" if username.text == "timdadum" and password.text == "mijnwachtwoord" else "login"
        root.manager.transition.direction = "left"

        # reset the textinputs to empty strings once pressed and processed
        self.username.text = ''
        self.password.text = ''

    def to_homescreen(self):
        print('Het werkt!')
        """
        Script om naar ander scherm te gaan
        """

# creating application class that consists of  MyFloatLayout
class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return kv

# This if-statement is gibberish for me as well as in idk why this is needed but oh well
if __name__ == '__main__':
    MyApp().run()
```

**kv file**

```
WindowManager:
    LoginWindow:
    HomeWindow:
    PreferencesWindow:

<Button>:
    font_size: 27
    size_hint: 0.2, 0.1
    background_color: 0.1, 0.5, 0.6, 1
<Label>:
    font_size: 18
    size_hint: 0.1, 0.05
    color: 0.1, 0.5, 0.6, 1
<TextInput>:
    font_size: 14
    size_hint: 0.3, 0.05

<LoginWindow>:
    name: "login"

    MyFloatLayout:
        username: username
        password: password

        Button:
            pos_hint:{'center_y':0.43, 'center_x': 0.5}
            id: btn
            text: "Login" if btn.state == "normal" else ""
            on_press: root.on_press()
            color: 1, 1, 1, 1

        Button:
            color: 1, 1, 1, 1
            text: "Home"
            id: to_homescreen
            on_press: root.to_homescreen()
            pos_hint:{'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.2}

        Label:
            pos_hint:{'center_y':0.57, 'center_x': 0.35}
            text: "Username"
        TextInput:
            pos_hint:{'center_y':0.57, 'center_x': 0.6}
            id: username
            multiline: False

        Label:
            pos_hint:{'center_y':0.5, 'center_x': 0.35}
            text: "Password"
        TextInput:
            pos_hint:{'center_y':0.5, 'center_x': 0.6}
            id: password
            multiline: False

<HomeWindow>:
    name: "home"

    Button:
        text: "Go back to login screen"
        on_release:
            app.root.current = "login"
            root.manager.transition.direction = "right"
```

Which yields the error:

```
    raise FactoryException('Unknown class <%s>' % name)
 kivy.factory.FactoryException: Unknown class <MyFloatLayout>
```

So something must be wrong with the way I call my class 'MyFloatLayout'. I've tried everything, nothing seems to work. If I change MyFloatLayout to a regular FloatLayout, it works properly (without the functionality of my own class MyFloatLayout, obviously). Some help would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The kv file will be loaded automatically with naming convention as you named it `my.kv` excluding the app part of the `MyApp` class. So you can exclude/comment out the line:

```
kv = Builder.load_file('my.kv')
```

And remove `kv` from the `return kv` statement.

Or you can rename the `my.kv` file to any other name and place the line `kv = Builder.load_file(<kv file name>)` after `MyFloatLayout` class definition. Otherwise there will be `unknown class` error raised.

Comment: Thank you for the reply! I'm aware that my.kv loads automatically with an app called MyApp.

I've removed the kv variable and the app class MyApp does not return that same variable anymore. Why is it that this works while what I had did not? When I changed the name of the kv variable and left the rest of the script the same it didn't work either. Is it simply because calling my.kv conflicts with automatic loading of my.kv?

Comment: I have updated the answer. The main issue is the loading of kv file before ```MyFloatLayout``` class definition. The ```kv = Builder.load_file(<kv file name>)``` line should be placed after ```MyFloatLayout``` class declaration. For the kv loading with default naming convention this is handled automatically. For kv file with other names, it needs to be make sure where the kv file loading is happening. Hope this is clear now.

Comment: If you use the default name ```my.kv``` and do explicit loading before ```MyFloatLayout``` class definition, then there will be double loading of the kv file. The automatic default loading will be successful, while the explicit loading would raise ```unknown class``` error. Which is exactly what happened with your code.